# Callback URL is not working in magento-1.9

Tags: magento, url, oauth, callback, magento-1.9

I am using magento-1.9 version and trying to generate oauth_token and oauth_token_secret.

reference link : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html

To get the oauth_verifier we need to give the callback URL. I am using this [http://localhost/magento/index.php?accepted](http://10.0.2.15/magento/index.php?accepted) link as callback URL. But this is not working.

Any one can help me to make this URL to work as callback URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Example of retrieving the products list using Admin account via Magento REST API. OAuth authorization is used
 * Preconditions:
 * 1. Install php oauth extension
 * 2. If you were authorized as a Customer before this step, clear browser cookies for 'yourhost'
 * 3. Create at least one product in Magento
 * 4. Configure resource permissions for Admin REST user for retrieving all product data for Admin
 * 5. Create a Consumer
 */
// $callbackUrl is a path to your file with OAuth authentication example for the Admin user

$baseUrl = 'http://yourhost.abc';
$scriptName = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$callbackUrl = 'http://scripthost.xyz' . $scriptName;
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = $baseUrl."/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = $baseUrl.'/admin/oauth_authorize';
$customerAuthorizationUrl = $baseUrl.'/oauth/authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = $baseUrl.'/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = $baseUrl.'/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'Your API consumer key';
$consumerSecret = 'Your API consumer key';

session_start();

if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $customerAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
        $productsList = json_decode(json_encode($oauthClient->getLastResponse()), FALSE);

        echo $productsList;
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
    echo "&lt;br/&gt;";
    print_r($e->lastResponse);
}

?>
```

/**
Also Callback URL is same as your PHP calling script. In other words you have to redirect to this script. Also your callback script and your server, both should on live server or on local server.
*/

Comment: 1- You may use $adminAuthorizationUrl for accessing Magento shop resources using Magento 1.x REST API as admin user.

2- You may use $customerAuthorizationUrl for accessing Magento shop resources using Magento 1.x REST API as customer user.

Comment: Check permission setting in your Magento admin panel: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/permission_settings/permission_settings.html

Comment: This doesn't work in 1.9.x, the callback url never gets fired for me either, with your exact code copied (and the two urls and the two keys updated), the callback is the same as set in the backend. The permissions are all configured. Does a theme need configured to work with the callback?